# is it possible to get the compiled function name by from google closure from within the code?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a section in code where I need to override the function by its name. 
A simplified version of it is here:

```
function override(obj, funcName){
   if(obj && obj[funcName])
      obj[funcName] = function(){ alert("Haha, now it's different func!"); }
   else
      console.error("Object does not contain function "+funcName);
}
```

It works perfectly, unless I compile it with Google Closure, then, of course, it doesn't, because function `obj.doSomethingBeneficial` becomes smth like `obj.qq`...

So the question is: is it possible to know, from within the code, what is compiled name of the function? Then I could override it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler recognizes a special function name which allows you to to rename a string in the same way a property would be renamed: [goog.reflect.objectProperty(prop name, obj)](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.reflect.html).  The function is part of closure-library, but you can define it yourself without including closure-library.

```
var goog = { reflect: { objectProperty: function(name, obj) { return name; } } };
if (obj && obj['funcName']) {
  obj[goog.reflect.objectProperty('funcName', obj)] =
      function(){ alert("Haha, now it's different func!"); };
} else {
  console.error("Object does not contain function "+ 'funcName');
}
```

The one caveat is that the first parameter to `goog.reflect.objectProperty` must be a string literal. You cannot use a variable.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I use it in my case, could you give an example? I just don't understand how could I make it clear for compiler that I want the shortened name for this particular object that I work on...

Comment: @shal added an example